# How to do mean in aggregate function with a condition in syntax in SPSS

Tags: spss, aggregation

I need to do mean in aggregate function by id and year with a condition. It should be simple - BUT couldn't make it.

An example:

```
ID year result
1  2011 50
1  2012 68
1  2012 45
2  2011 12
2  2011 80
2  2012 20
```

but I don't understand where to put the condition:

```
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE='test'
  /BREAK=CUSTOMER_ID CUSTOMERIDCD year
  /test_mean_under60=MEAN(result) **IF result > 60**
  /N_BREAK=N.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do conditional statements in `AGGREGATE`. One way to accomplish your end goal though is to use `TEMPORARY.` and `SELECT IF` before the aggregate. Example below:

```
DATA LIST FREE / Id year result.
BEGIN DATA
1  2011 50
1  2012 68
1  2012 45
2  2011 12
2  2011 80
2  2012 20
END DATA.

DATASET DECLARE test.
TEMPORARY.
SELECT IF result > 60.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE='test'
  /BREAK = ID year
  /test_mean_over60 = MEAN(result)
  /N_BREAK=N.
EXECUTE.
```